# On the range of positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A = P_1 + \ldots + P_n$ is the sum of positive semidefinite matrices. We seek to prove $range(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n range(P_i)$.

$range(A) \subset \sum_{i=1}^n range(P_i)$. We have $ker(A) \subset ker(P_i)$ for all $i$ since $P_i \leq A$. Here's what I don't understand: it follows that $range(P_i) \subset range(A)$? I don't see how this is a direct result of the rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank nullity theorem isn't enough on its own, you need an additional fact about symmetric (and therefore also positive semidefinite) matrices.  Namely, if $A$ is symmetric, then
$$
\ker(A) = \operatorname{range}(A)^\perp
$$